# What are the systemctl options to "List all failed units"

Tags: systemd

```
systemctl
```

Returns a list of the units, whether they are loaded, active, their sub and description.

```
systemctl is-failed
```

Returns a list of status only.

What is the syntax to return the details of the failed units?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

You can use `systemctl list-units --state=failed` to list all failed units.

The parameters for systemctl are documented in the man page [systemctl(1)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html).

Comment: `--failed` is an alias for `--state=failed`

Comment: Yes thats right, but until 2017-02-02 `--failed` wasn't documented and marked as deprecated in the codebase ([#5198](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/5198))

Comment: I see. And from the PR discussion I learned that we can drop `list-units` and go with `systemctl --failed` by itself :)

Comment: I find it very irritating that `systemctl status` tells me the one+ things are failed, but wont tell me what. I need to run another command, not under the `status` subcommand to find out. Shame.

Comment: @NathanLilienthal request a change from the systemd folks. They are quite opinionated on "the one right way of doing things", though.

Answer (score 33):

This is more simple:

`systemctl --failed`