# How can I list the queued units with systemctl?

Tags: systemd

My `systemctl status` shows:

```
● mymachine
     State: running
     Jobs: 4 queued
```

**How can I list the `queued` jobs?**

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341061/100270) shows how to list the failed units, but I can't find any docs on how to list those 4 queued units, nor is it clear to me which state in `systemctl list-units --state=help` corresponds to those.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is: **`systemctl list-jobs`**

Example output:

```
# systemctl list-jobs
 JOB UNIT                                  TYPE  STATE  
3543 nginxAfterGlusterfs.service           start waiting
3545 glusterReadyForLocalhostMount.service start running
3506 nginx.service                         start waiting

4 jobs listed.
```

Those units also have a `start` entry in the `JOB` column in the `systemctl` table.